# which context.getBean to use when get the bean from spring

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

In the following link 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/quick-tour.html

It defined a bean in XML like

```
<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
```

Then in the calling code, it used

```
AmqpTemplate template = context.getBean(AmqpTemplate.class);
```

Why it used

```
context.getBean(AmqpTemplate.class);
```

instead of

```
 context.getBean("amqpTemplate");
```

What's the getBean(AmqpTemplate.class) means? I can't find it defined by xml.

Answer (score 1):

If you used `context.getBean("amqpTemplate")` you would need to cast the result to AmqpTemplate while `getBean(AmqpTemplate.class)` does it automatically. Note that `getBean(AmqpTemplate.class)` can only work if you have only one bean with AmqpTemplate class in the context

Answer (score 1):

```
getBean()
```

is an overloaded method. You can call with the bean name or a bean type. Calling with the class returns the single instance of this class type. If there are more than one throws an exception. If there are none again throws an exception.

See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-).